# tax_query not working on custom post type

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

For some reason my tax_query is returning 0 posts.  I'm able to assign posts to the Tax and the archive pages work correctly.  When I try to create the below custom query the post_count in the WP_QUERY object is 0.  Please help!

TAXONOMY REGISTRATION:

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'member_resources_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
    'member_resources',        //post type name
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'label' => 'Categories',  //Display name
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member-resource-category','with_front' => true),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'member-resource-category',
    )  
);
```

WP_QUERY args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'member_resources',
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'member_resources_categories',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'background-on-tent'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Well, do you have published posts in the `background-on-tent` term? And try inspecting the `request` property of the query object, e.g. `$query = new WP_Query( $args ); var_dump( $query->request );`. Also, that `'status'    => 'publish'` should actually be `'post_status'    => 'publish'` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for your response.  Yes, there are published posts in the background-on-tent term.

Here is the output of the request property of the query object:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  0 = 1
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'member_resources' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: Where did you put your code - in what template file and hook if any?

Comment: @SallyCJ I just figured it out and you're on the right track.  I'm an idiot.  It just hit me.  I was running it in the functions.php file but I didn't put it within a function that ran after WP loaded.  So the tax or post type likely wasn't registered yet...  I've worked almost 12 hours today...  I'm stepping away for a moment lol  Thank you!